# What is the shortest way to convert a bitmask to a list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dealing with hardware so the priors are kind of fixed, I'm afraid.

I've got a bitmask in the form of a byte and I need to create a list of strings based on the values of each bit so that I can print out which bits are "on".

I could do this with an enum and a bunch of code but I'm wondering if there's a simpler shorter way that I'm overlooking.

```
bitmap = 127
result_list = your_code_here(bitmap)
print(*result_list, sep = ", ")
```

Expected output where `FlagN` is printed only if there is a `1` in that position of the of the binary `bitmap`.

```
Flag1, Flag2, Flag3,
```

Comment: What exactly goes into the function with the bitmask? In other words, what are we applying the bitmask *to*?

Comment: whats the sample input and expcted output

Comment: Are you looking for: `list(f'{127:08b}') == ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']`?

Comment: So you have an array of strings already? eg `['Booted', 'Enabled', 'Communicating', ...]` and you want to select some of those based on the bitmask of a byte? So a byte starting `110 `(ignoring endianness) would output `Booted Enabled`, whereas `001` would output `Communicating`?

Comment: @Basic yes that works.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle the input is bitmap.  I've edited to show the expected output.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I've changed the OP from "bitmask" to "bitmap" . I hope that's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a list/hashtable of corresponding values for each bit, and then take and print values from that list depending on whether the bit is flipped:

```
flags = ['Booted',
         'Enabled',
         'Communicating',
         ...]
bitmask = int(input("Input the bitmask: "))
print([flag for (index, flag) in enumerate(flags) if (bitmask & 2**index)])
```

e.g. inputting `5` as a bitmask (that is, `0b101`) would output `['Booted', 'Communicating']`.

Comment: That's good but what I was already thinking of.  Is there a shorter way?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to prioritize - theoretically you could use a hashtable for this approach instead, or try to cook up something more complicated. But before doing so, ask yourself *why that's necessary*? This solution is, given the flags and the bitmask (which both need to be defined anyway), one line long - what do you mean by "shorter"? Python may not be able to provide what you need, if you need hyper-efficiency and speed.

Comment: Due diligence on my part.  I'm always trying to make my code more concise and Pythonic.

Comment: more concise is not always a good thing. dont let minimalist code take away from code readability just cuase you want to make it 10 chars shorter